Send out Power BI reports via Email
I need to migrate reports from QlikSense to Power BI. These reports are usually sent out by email every month to each employee with their scores on selected KPIs.
Until now, NPrinting was used - this is a Qlik tool that allows the automatic generation and distribution of reports to specific groups of recipients. There was a task created in NPrinting that needed to be manually ran, and after completion, all recipients will receive an email. That email contained HTML version of the report directly visible in the email, and in the same email would be attached an excel version of the report.
When migrating this to Power BI, I would like to keep the email similar, or at least have an excel or pdf file attached. I do not expect HTML version at all.
There are ideas in the web like subscribing to a report that will automatically send reports, but we do not send out reports on a specific date every month, the day of month is different every time.
I think it would work to simply automatically send an email with a link to the report in the workspace, but I am not sure if all recipients should get Premium license.
Edit 1: I tried using Power Automate, but it requires a Trigger - either an event (like report refresh, refresh fail, certain value goes up, etc....) or recurring event (meaning I need to schedule it once per month on specific day and time). None of this works in this case. I think Power Automate will be the way to go if I can work a way around these triggers.
Edit 2: I succeeded in creating a Power Automate Flow, and send it to myself, but it will not keep the RLS, because it generates the report before sending out, and all recipient will get the same copy (I think it takes the RLS restriction for the person who triggers the task - mine in this case).

You have only a few options:
For automated reports, with the RLS applied, you need to get the users to use subscribe to the report. But as you mentioned, this is based on a schedule, but your requirement is more ad-hoc in terms of the day. You would have to use after 'data refresh' option.
You could use a Power Automate, to trigger this dataset refresh, you would have to have some sort of data source with a list of dates in it, to trigger the refresh on a certain day, and do some sort of compare to that value and the current date.
Your last option is to have another Power Automate that you can trigger, to refresh the dataset then send out an email with a link to the report in the workspace.
For your question about the type of license, users will need a Power BI Pro license for a subscription.
